# permanent flags for google chrome linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, unix, ubuntu

I would like to set permanent flags for google chrome.
I found [this](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/) but it only describes how to do it with .desktop file
I dont have desktop file and I dont want it. I create keyboard shortcut to 
run google chrome (win+W) with flags that I want. It fits to me well.
But is there a way to always run google chrome with my flags no matter how I run it? For example ALT+F2 and just run google-chrome

I am using kubuntu 14.04

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

As a possible solution you can create shell wrapper to run chrome with required flags. It can have different name or you can rename original google-chrome script and create our with the same name.

For example rename /usr/bin/google-chrome to /usr/bin/google-chrome-orig and create new script /usr/bin/google-chrome:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/google-chrome-orig --allow-file-access-from-files
```